# How can I export .hdr or .exr image from iPhone HDRI photo (.HEIC format)?

Tags: iphone, hdr, openexr, heic

I want to take HDR photos with my iPhone and get images as .hdr or .exr image formats, in order to use them for my cinema rendering purpose.

I took some HDR photos with my iPhone X and sent them to my iMac, and then I tried converting them from .HEIC format to .exr format with sips command like below:

```
sips -s format exr image.HEIC
```

However, it turned out that output .exr images seemed not to be adequate OpenEXR images. Actually I tried to import one of the images with OpenCV in Python and checked its max RGB value on numpy ndarray like below, but it was just 1.0, although there was obviously very bright light there.

```
img = np.array(cv.imread(img_path, cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH))
print(img.max())
```

How can I get HDR images in the right way with my iPhone? If you know any other better ways to do that, can you tell me about it? Thank you.